# Is it possible to have a custom region shape? Core Location

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, core-location, geofencing

For example at least I want a square/rectangle/ the shape of the road to be my region.

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not. As per the the documentation, currently the only region classes are CLCircularRegion, which is obviously circular, and CLBeaconRegion which is based on the proximity to an iBeacon. It is possible in the future that apple will add support for custom shaped regions but as of iOS 8, this is it.

https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLRegion_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLRegion