# Create a custom shape polygon as a region for geofencing?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation, geofencing

Currently we have an array of coordinates, the coordinates will outline a rectangle shape.

```
  var coordinatesArray: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

    override init() {
        super.init()

 //top left
        coordinatesArray.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.7915055, longitude: -96.8028408))
        //top right
        coordinatesArray.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.7919914, longitude: -96.8022031))
        //bottom left
        coordinatesArray.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:  32.7910108, longitude: -96.8025008))
        //bottom right
        coordinatesArray.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.7915926, longitude: -96.8016962))

}
```

As of now, it asks for a circular region to monitor:

```
let geoFenceRegion:CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.7915926, -96.8016962), radius: 100, identifier: "Dallas")
```

What we want is the geofence to fit the shape of the coordinates. I saw this post from a few years ago stating that you can't create custom regions:

[custom shape region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990480/is-it-possible-to-have-a-custom-region-shape-core-location)

Is this even possible to create a custom shape region?

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know geofences are always circular. You could combine multiple smaller circular regions to create a shape closer to what you want (although there is a fairly small limit to the total number of location regions (20 total, if memory serves)

Comment: Or perhaps use a bounding circle and then re-check against the rectangle when it fires.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using third party API like TomTom's API. You can create circles, ploygons, corridors, store them in the cloud and even trigger an event if a tracking object entering, exiting or dwelling.

https://developer.tomtom.com/geofencing-api/geofencing-api-documentation